# Функции insert()

Tags: c++

Вводятся две строки, необходимо в первой строке найти вторую и заключить ее в скобки. "s3.insert(1,s2)" без этой команды программа работает, с этой командой программа зависает. Подскажите в чем проблема.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    string s1,s2,s3;
    cout<<"Введите первую строку: ";
    cin>>s1;
    cout<<"Введите вторую строку: ";
    cin>>s2;
    s3="()";
    s3.insert(1,s2);

    int size = s2.size();

    int x = s1.find (s2);
    while (x<s1.size()){
        s1.replace(x, size, s3);
        x = s1.find (s2);
    }

    cout<<s1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно найти все вхождения строки s2 в s1, то цикл здесь нужен.
Проблема в том, что следующее вхождение нужно искать не с начала строки, как вы это делали здесь:

`x = s1.find (s2);`

а с определённого индекса, то есть (предыдущий x + длина найденной строки)

`x = s1.find(s2, x + s3.size());`

Итого:

```
int x = s1.find(s2);
while (x != string::npos) {
    s1.replace(x, size, s3);
    x = s1.find(s2, x + s3.size());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Например, такая функция вернет вам то что нужно:

```
string&
enclose(string& s1, const string& s2,
        const char ch1 = '(', const char ch2 = ')')
{
    size_t first = s1.find(s2); 
     if (first != string::npos) {
        auto p = s1.insert(s1.begin() + first, ch1);
        s1.insert(p + s2.size() + 1, ch2);
     }
    return s1;
}
```

Нет необходимости в дополнительном обьекте....

Comment: а если нет включения искомой строки? Ваша функция содержит серьезную ошибку

Comment: К тому же не думаю, что разумно использовать целочисленный тип для возвращаемого значения функции, которая использует отрицательное значение для сигнала об ошибке.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch,  нетрудно найти во многих ответах неучтенные  деталии и ставить минусы. А разве это делу поможет?...

Comment: я поставил минус потому что в вашем ответе (была) не "неучтенный минус" - а серьезная ошибка, разве нет? Вы с этим не согласны? Но в любом случае, так как ошибка исправлена, мой минус я аннулирую

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, в таких случаях, для общего блага,  любезно предупреждают об упущении.  Но вы зря   аннулировали минус, поскольку  побольшому счету я должен был кинуть исключение, если строка не найдена, или как минимум, вывести сообщение на консоль.

Comment: а я разве не предупредил в комментарии об ошибке? Я только что проверил и под вашим вопросом стоит: а если нет включения искомой строки? Ваша функция содержит серьезную ошибку - что является моим комментарием. Так в чем у вас притензия? Он недостаточно информативен или не любезен? Мне нужно было рассыпаться в любезностях? Извините, но я не понимаю к чему вы тут докапываетесь? Вы совершили ошибку из-за которой ваш ответ был не просто бесполезен, но и вреден, так как функция портила данные. За это и был минус.

Comment: Если вам уж так неимется, то можете и мне минус поставить - я как-нибудь переживу это, даже если вы и не напишите в чем была проблема, из-за которой вы минус поставили)))

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch,  не знаю что для вас означают эти минусы и плюсы..  По мне  они предназначены больше для широкой публики и должны быть полезны именно для них, поскольку сами ответы явлются попыткой помочь, а не показать свои знания... По поводу вашего ответа:  не проверил, но насколько я понимаю, код не должен работать.  По поводу моего ответа:  я в  последнем предложении допустил ошибку, но исправил

Comment: "не знаю что для вас означают эти минусы и плюсы.. По мне они предназначены больше для широкой публики и должны быть полезны именно для них, поскольку сами ответы явлются попыткой помочь, а не показать свои знания.." - В ЭТОМ И ДЕЛО!!!!! Вы допустили, скажем прямо, грубейшую ошибку из-за которой ваш код был ВРЕДЕН! И за это минус - чтобы показать публике, что это НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ! Ну вот вы сами себя почитайте и подумайте! И по поводу какого "моего ответа", который не должен работать вы написали? Я что-то не вижу, чтобы СДЕСЬ в комментах я прилагал какой-то код

Answer (score 3):

Через метод `find` находим позицию начала строки s2 в строке s1. Если `find` не вернул `std::string::npos`, значит подстрока найдена, вставляем скобки методом `insert`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string s1,s2;

    std::cout << "first string: ";
    std::cin >> s1;

    std::cout << "second string: ";
    std::cin >> s2;

    int pos = s1.find(s2);

    if(pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        s1.insert(pos, "(");
        s1.insert(pos+s2.length()+1, ")");
        std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Substring not found!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> first string: foobar
>
> second string: bar
>
> Sucess!
>
> foo(bar)

Answer (score 2):

Ну так а что вы делаете сдесь:

```
int x = s1.find (s2);
while (x<s1.size()){
    s1.replace(x, size, s3);
    x = s1.find (s2);
}
```

?
У вас всегда условие в цикле будет верным!! Так как если искомая строка есть в `s1`, то `x`, конечно, будет меньше `size`. А если нет, то `x` будет равен `-1`, и тоже меньше чем `size`.

И зачем вам сдесь вообще цикл? Разве не достаточно простого `if`?

```
int x = s1.find (s2);
if (x != -1){
    s1.replace(x, size, s3);
    x = s1.find (s2);
}
```

Так все работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int x = s1.find (s2);
    while (x<s1.size()){
        s1.replace(x, size, s3);
        x = s1.find (s2);
    }
```

при осутствии `find` возвращает `std::string::npos == -1` , то есть в любом случае бесконечный цикл. Баг в алгоритме ещё, вы в переменной `s1` не удаляете найденную строку, а делаете `replace` , при `s1 == s2` будет опять зависон. Демонстрация этой проблемы:

```
# include <string>
# include <iostream>
int main(){
std::string s1("abc");
std::string s2("a");
int size = s2.size();
std::string s3("aa");
int x = std::string::npos ;
if (x == -1) std::cout<<"std::string::npos == -1"<<std::endl;
else std::cout<<"std::string::npos != -1"<<std::endl;
size_t limit = 10 ;
x = s1.find (s2) ;
while ((x not_eq std::string::npos) and limit){
        s1.replace(x, size, s3);
        std::cout<<"s1="<<s1<<std::endl;
        x = s1.find (s2); 
    -- limit ;   }
if(not limit)  std::cout<<"Zavison!"<<std::endl;}
```

результат:

```
std::string::npos == -1
s1=aabc
s1=aaabc
s1=aaaabc
s1=aaaaabc
s1=aaaaaabc
s1=aaaaaaabc
s1=aaaaaaaabc
s1=aaaaaaaaabc
s1=aaaaaaaaaabc
s1=aaaaaaaaaaabc
Zavison!
```

Comment: Не совсем согласен по поводу последнего предложения - это не является проблемой.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вы не правы - ровняется. Вот смотрите: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos. Можете проверить

Comment: @AlexGlebe у вас `Zavison!` не из-за `replace` а из-за того, что цикл, все еще, реализован не верно. Что это за условие: `x != std::string::npos`? При первом же заходе в тело у вас x всегда будет != -1

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch не волнуётесь у меня всё пучком. Лучше предложите алгоритм достойный.

Comment: я уже предложил, просто вы не правы, когда говорите, что сдесь проблема из-за `replace` - вы неверно сделали цикл и именно из-за этого проблема. Посмотрите ответ Влада Мамутова - у него цикл построен верно и, имхо, это лучший ответ на данный вопрос.

Comment: я всего лишь показал где лажи, результат достойный у Мамутова конечно.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch ,   я подумал об  string::find,  а  написал   string::npos,  просто сам ошибся, так что нет нужды проверять

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну вообще string::find возвращает string::npos если не было найдено вхождение...

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, вот именно. я специально отметил   string::find , поскольку она возвращает  беззнаковый тип,  и  некорректно сравнивать ее с -1.  Другое дело, что static size_t string::npos  ==   -1  по  определению В этом случаи  -1  просто преобразовывается в  большое беззнаковое число, и  string::npos принимает это значение, но сравнивать  его значение с -1  некорректно , и компилятор может выдать предупреждение.     Вот так я должен был написать,  дабы не запутать никого. Потому я убрал  свой комментарий...